# Failure in loading image to cell in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, ios8

I have just started using swift. I am using blocks and `NSOperationQueue` to download the image in `tableViewCell` and in the completion handler I am returning the downloaded image. I am trying to update the cell as below.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("itemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        var itemImage = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UIImageView
        var itemName = cell.viewWithTag(1001) as! UILabel

        if let item = self.itemArray?[indexPath.row] {
            itemImage.image = UIImage(named: "Placeholder.jpg")
            getImageForItem(item, withCompletion: { (image) -> () in
                if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                    var imageViewToUpdate = cellToUpdate.viewWithTag(1000) as! UIImageView
                    imageViewToUpdate.image = image
                }
            })

            itemName.text = item.itemName
            }
        return cell
    }

func getImageForItem(item: item, withCompletion completion:((image: UIImage) -> ())) {
        if let image = self.imageCache.objectForKey(item.itemID) as? UIImage {
            completion(image: image)
        } else {
            let request = item.getItemImage(ItemImageSize(rawValue: 2)!, withWidth: 100, shouldFetch: false, block: { (image, tempID) -> Void in
                if image != nil {
                    self.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: item.itemID)

                    if item.itemID == tempID {
                        completion(image: image)
                    }
                }
            })
            if request != nil {
                imageQueue.addOperation(request)
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem I face is, I am getting the image successfully in the completion block of cellForRowAtIndexPath(), but, I fail to update the cell. For the above code, the downloaded image is applied to all the visible cells in the tableView, but, as I scroll down, I see only the placeholder image. Even I loose the loaded images to placeholder image on scrolling back.

On debugging, I found that

```
if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                    var imageViewToUpdate = cellToUpdate.viewWithTag(1000) as! UIImageView
                    imageViewToUpdate.image = image
                }
```

loop is called for the visible cells only first time. But not called again on scrolling. What am I missing?

Comment: When you need the same image in all cell, you should download it in `viewDidLoad` and store it in the controller.

Comment: I am not using the same image for all cells

Comment: in wwdc session 231 _Cocoa Touch Best Practices_ they encouraged to avoid `setTag:` and `viewWithTag:` **Instance variables and properties provide better alternative** also I suggest using `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h` for image downloading, it make it easier by just calling  `- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
       placeholderImage:(nullable UIImage *)placeholderImage;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted out myself. I added one more argument, indexPath to track it.

```
getImageForItem(item, indexPath: indexPath, withCompletion: { (image, imageIndexPath) -> () in
                if Set<NSIndexPath>(tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows() as! [NSIndexPath]).contains(imageIndexPath) {
                    itemImage.image=image
                }
            })
```

That gave me the perfect solution